# Excel find equal values and multiply another cell

Tags: arrays

I have a sheet the the followin info

```
"A" "B"
_____
a   1
a   1
a   1
a   1
a   1
a   1
b   1
b   1
b   0
b   1
b   1
b   1
c   1
c   0
c   1
d   1
d   1
```

I Like to have an Array formula that multiplies al values on column "B" that have the same text on column "A"

I don't whant to use a pivot table, i need to solve this with formulas.

End result should be on column "C"

```
a = 1
b = 0
c = 0
d = 1
```

thanks

Comment: You can use vba for solve this question

Answer (score 0):

I can do it in two columns....

Column C formula
    =IF(A3=A2,C3*B2,B2)

Column D formula
    =IF(A2<>A1,CONCATENATE(A2," = ",C2),"")

gives results like this
[Excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgTTK.png)

if the blanks are a problem,
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/NoBlanks.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DPRODUCT() might do it, as well, if you can setup the criteria correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OK i solved using this formula as array

```
=+SI(SUMA(SI((A:A=A1);B:B;0))=CONTAR.SI(A:A;A1);"OK";"")
```